# Peltier Module Heating Problem

Tags: arduino, peltier

I am employing a small Peltier module with Arduino as its power source. In order to achieve a temperature of 80°C, I require 4.4V. Despite supplying 5V through Arduino, the module is not generating the desired heat. Any recommendations on how I should proceed?

Comment: Show us the datasheet for your module. My guess is you are overloading the onboard regulator. Even the smallest peltier needs more power than an arduino can provide.  Hopefully you are using the onboard 5V instead of a GPIO in which case your board is likely dead.

Comment: @vir At least the I/O pin is.

Comment: As written already, you shouldn't power much else than LED's etc with an Arduinos pins. Instead get an external power source for the peltier, and if needed, you can switch on and off the peltier from the Arduino through a MOSFET or a relay.

Comment: Remember that a Peltier creates a temperature difference. If you want maximum heat on one side, you need to keep the other side near ambient.

Comment: an arduino cannot be used as a power source ... it can only be used for control

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize an N-channel MOSFET and separate power for the Peltier. Since you haven't provided much more than voltage a couple of candidates that can take a few amps are the [IRL540N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRL540N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153565fc2a62567) and the [IRLB8721](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLB8721-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566056732591). Both have low Rds(on) in the tenths of milliOhms at 5 V, can control more than 30 A and are easy to work with (through hole).

***Example:***

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6VKWd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Furthermore as Mattman944 writes, you need to sink heat into the cool side of the Peltier, for maximum effect.